# How to switch to asynchronous fetching image from string url on watchOS?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

My current code for fetching image from String with `SwiftUI` is:

```
import SwiftUI
struct NetworkImage: View {
    let url: URL?
    var body: some View {
        if let url = url, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }
    }
}
```

It is fine when I use it using `WidgetKit` on **iOS**. But it doesn't work when I am trying to use the same on **watchOS**.

Error on console:

> Synchronous URL loading of `https://www.imageurl.here` should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73847361/2725435) question does not answer my question as of it is not with UIKit, but with SwiftUI on `watchOS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `iOS 15` and `watchOS 8.0` it can be done using:

```
AsyncImage(url: url)
```

If there is a need to access an image and modify it directly use closure:

```
AsyncImage(url: url) { phase in
    phase.image?
        .resizable() // example
        .scaledToFill() // example
}
```